# Java math function to convert positive int to negative and negative to positive?

Tags: java, math

Is there a Java function to convert a positive int to a negative one and a negative int to a positive one?

I'm looking for a `reverse` function to perform this conversion:

```
-5  ->  5
 5  -> -5
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348080/convert-a-positive-number-to-negative-in-c-sharp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213338/fastest-way-to-flip-the-sign-of-a-double-float-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866187/how-to-flip-the-sign-of-an-integer-value-using-some-constant-and-operators-wit

Comment: int x = 5; x = -x;

Answer (score 282, accepted):

What about `x *= -1;` ? Do you really want a library function for this?

Comment: @pst No it won't. At least not with JDK 1.6.0_11 ;D

Comment: For me the wrong answer has been accepted. It is a valid answer, but given that the OP is asking to change sign of an int, so there is no concern about negative zero or other concepts, I would suggest x = -x is more expressive (see EJP's answer below)...

Comment: Addendum to previous comment: see also Bohemian's answer as it explains the unary operator in more detail

Comment: @drrob You do realize that any decent compiler will anyway use x = -x right?

Comment: @FailedDev sure, but I said it is more expressive (not better for performance)

Comment: this answer is not correct. int has the minimum value of -2^31 and a maximum value of 2^31-1 which means that in the particular case when you need to convert Integer.MIN_VALUE this will NOT work and also will not throw an exception (what I think it is really bad)

Answer (score 115):

```
x = -x;
```

This is probably the most trivial question I have ever seen anywhere.

... and why you would call this trivial function 'reverse()' is another mystery.

Comment: This does not work in the case where x = Integer.MIN_VALUE and will silently fail*. To be safe, you should check for this case and throw an exception, or use the library function negateExact, which does exactly that.

Comment: @rdllopes The same applies to practically every answer here.

Comment: Note though that it won't compile if x is short or byte, whereas `x *= -1` will. Was a bit surprised when I discovered that which is how I came across this page :) Of course you can cast, but I was auto-generating code where x could be byte, short, int or long...

Comment: @DaveGriffiths You were autogenerating code to change the sign of a variable?

Comment: Yeah - parsing something where the sign appears after the number :)

Comment: @rdllopes In fact it applies to every possible answer. When `x == `Integer.MIN_VALUE` *there is no solution.*

Comment: Well, I provided the safe solution. Now, noticed that I just gave a comment for one corner case. As programmers we should have that in mind if the problem might fall in that case. Otherwise, your solution is really good.

Comment: And if the value is already negative and he wants to convert it to positive? Then your answer fails.

Answer (score 56):

Just use the *unary minus operator*:

```
int x = 5;
...
x = -x; // Here's the mystery library function - the single character "-"
```

Java has *two* minus [operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html):

- the familiar *arithmetic* version (eg `0 - x`), and
- the *unary minus operation* (used here), which negates the (single) operand

This compiles and works as expected.

Answer (score 11):

Another method (2's complement):

```
public int reverse(int x){
    x~=x;
    x++;
    return x;
}
```

It does a one's complement first (by complementing all the bits) and then adds 1 to x. This method does the job as well.

Note: This method is written in Java, and will be similar to a lot of other languages

Comment: In reality don't do this, just do `x = -x`. From an assembly perspective, `-x` is a simple `neg` instruction while `~x` and `++x` requires a `not` and `add` instruction.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, as was already noted by [Jeffrey Bosboom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3614835/jeffrey-bosboom) (Sorry Jeffrey, I hadn't noticed your comment when I answered), there is such a function: [Math.negateExact](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#negateExact-int-).

and

No, you probably shouldn't be using it.  Not unless you need a [method reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Comment: There are other cases where it makes sense to use it, such as if you need the robustness of rejecting overflows.

Answer (score 6):

No such function exists or is possible to write.

The problem is the edge case Integer.MIN_VALUE (-2,147,483,648 = 0x80000000) apply each of the three methods above and you get the same value out. This is due to the representation of integers and the maximum possible integer Integer.MAX_VALUE (-2,147,483,647 = 0x7fffffff) which is one less what -Integer.MIN_VALUE should be.

Comment: If you want your code to be robust against this corner case, Java 8 provides [Math.negateExact](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#negateExact-int-) that will throw an `ArithmeticException` when trying to negate MIN_VALUE, rather than silently returning the wrong result.

Answer (score 5):

original *= -1;

Simple line of code, original is any int you want it to be.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest thing to do is 0- the value

for instance if int i = 5;

0-i would give you -5

and if i was -6;

0- i would give you 6

Comment: somehow I only can think of `* (-1)`, instead of using ` 0 -`. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Necromancing here. 
Obviously, `x *= -1;` is far too simple.

Instead, we could use a trivial binary complement:

```
number = ~(number - 1) ;
```

Like this:

```
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int iPositive = 15;
        int iNegative = ( ~(iPositive - 1) ) ; // Use extra brackets when using as C preprocessor directive ! ! !...
        System.out.println(iNegative);

        iPositive =  ~(iNegative - 1)  ;
        System.out.println(iPositive);

        iNegative = 0;
        iPositive = ~(iNegative - 1);
        System.out.println(iPositive);


    }
}
```

That way we can ensure that mediocre programmers don't understand what's going on ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the minus operator or Math.abs. These work for all negative integers EXCEPT for Integer.MIN_VALUE!
If you do 0 - MIN_VALUE the answer is still MIN_VALUE.

Answer (score 0):

For converting a negative number to positive. Simply use Math.abs() inbuilt function.

```
int n = -10;
n = Math.abs(n);
```

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Adding my 2 cents.

```java
public static int reverse(int value) {
    return Integer.valueOf(0).compareTo(value * value) * value;
}
```

Tip : you can replace `0` with `java.math.BigDecimal.ZERO` or `java.math.BigInteger.ZERO`.

---

To test it (i.e. on tio.run) :

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print(5);
        print(-5);
    }

    public static int reverse(int value) {
        return Integer.valueOf(0).compareTo(value * value) * value;
    }

    public static void print(int i) {
        System.out.printf("\nReversed %s to %s .", i, reverse(i));
    }
}
```

Prints :

```bash
Reversed 5 to -5 .
Reversed -5 to 5 .
```

Processing time : 0.106 s.

Instead of doing the `x` to `-x` thing.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 5;
        print(x);
        x = -5;
        print(x);
    }

    public static void print(int i) {
        System.out.printf("\nReversed %s to %s .", i, -i);
    }
}
```

Processing time : 0.108 s

Answer (score -2):

In kotlin you can use unaryPlus and unaryMinus

```
input = input.unaryPlus()
```

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/unary-plus.html
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/unary-minus.html

Answer (score -4):

You can use Math:

```
int x = Math.abs(-5);
```

Comment: How does this turn `5` into `-5`?

Comment: May be `var = Math.abs(var) * -1;`

Comment: This is blatantly wrong. `Math.abs()` just removes every `-` sign. It does not invert the sign. Use `-x` or `x * -1` instead.